# GRPC - why does `CallInvoker` need to impose `TRequest: class` and `TResponse: class`?

Tags: .net, f#, grpc

The signature defined by the abstract class `CallInvoker` in `Grpc.Core` imposes a type constraint `class` on both `TRequest` and `TResponse`. This prevents the use of structs as responses for the remote method, e.g. it doesn't work with F# result type `Result<'a, 'b>` as the response type, as F# `Result<_, _>` is a struct type.

Why does `CallInvoker` need to impose `TRequest: class` and `TResponse: class`?

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Api/CallInvoker.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at this in the past, as I wanted to propose removing it for protobuf-net.Grpc (which works fine with F#, btw); there's no *fundamental* reason, other than the code uses the sentinel `null` in many places to have meaning - and all of those scenarios would need changing, presumably to tuple-like type that encodes "has value" and "value" (essentially `Nullable<T>` but for any `T`); and that's quite a lot of work.

I'm open to giving it a try, though; it might actually be easier than the workaround I was planning for protobuf-net.Grpc (involving wrapping value-types on the fly).

For now, you'll have to use F# reference types. As an example, [this work fine with protobuf-net.Grpc](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/blob/master/examples/pb-net-grpc/Shared_FS/MyContracts.fs):

```ml
[<DataContract; CLIMutable>]
type MultiplyRequest =
    { [<DataMember(Order = 1)>] X : int
      [<DataMember(Order = 2)>] Y : int }

[<DataContract; CLIMutable>]
type MultiplyResult =
    { [<DataMember(Order = 1)>] Result : int }

[<ServiceContract(Name = "Hyper.Calculator")>]
type ICalculator =
    abstract MultiplyAsync : MultiplyRequest -> ValueTask<MultiplyResult>
```

Comment: Thank you, Marc, for the quick response. Indeed, I ran into this when using protobuf-net.Grpc. It would be great if that type constraint would be removed.

Comment: @LV I suspect a major complication may be that the Google implementation for a lot of this may be in the unmanaged library; if so: I'm not touching that with a barge pole

Comment: I would like to communicate also the erroneous case back to the client, so I ended up redefining the F# `Result<_, _>` type with `type GrpcResponse<'a, 'b> = Success of 'a | Failed of 'b`.

Comment: Yeah, that is totally understandable.

Comment: @LV it *could* just be bits like this, though: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Internal/ClientResponseStream.cs#L42

Comment: That would be a happy case. Btw, since we are on the topic, any plan to support F# DU in protobuf-net.Grpc in the near future?

Comment: @LV pretend I rarely touch F#; define "DU"? also, see here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/22605

Comment: @LV oh, discriminated unions? Good question: I'm not a huge F# user, but: in theory this would work *fairly* well with `oneof`, but it depends a lot on what F# does with it behind the scenes; can I suggest you propose it on the protobuf-net.Grpc repo along with a suitable DU type that I can play with, and I'll investigate how much work would be required - note: this would almost certainly be a protobuf-net v3 feature only

Comment: Yes, I should have been clearer, it was discriminated unions. I submitted the suggestion https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/issues/81